# Как избежать пустого вывода?

Tags: c++

Есть ли такая функция, что если ничего не вывелось(empty result), то выводить что-то?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138247/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 3):

```
bool wasOutput = false;
for(...;...;...)
{
     ... ваш код ...
     
     {   // Блок вывода
         cout << "Вывод" << endl;
         wasOutput = true;  // Запоминаем, что вывод был
     }
     ... ваш код ...

}
if (!wasOutput) cout << "Вывода не было";
```

Примерно так...